# tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: looks awful if not setting the next viewcontroller's background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

When I tried to push a view controller using `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, the transition did work certainly, but its animation looks quite awful; when I tapped any cell in UITableView, one third of the entire screen first became black (but the other two thirds are still UITableViewCell of the original screen!) and with a little bit of delay, the entire screen turned black.

I wonder why `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method acts in such a terrible way in terms of user-interface. Here's my code to make the transition:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    People *people = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailViewController.title = people.type1;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

However, if I change the `animated:` to `NO`, the transition doesn't have any issue (in terms of UI, again; that's what I'm asking here), but it changes to the new view controller instantly (naturally, since it's what the animated:NO do in the first place).

And the answer to this strange behavior is to set `backgroundColor` of the second view controller BEFORE executing `pushViewController: animated:` method, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255657/ios-7-uitableview-didselectrowatindexpath-pushviewcontroller-programmatically-a).

I wonder WHY I have to set background color before making the transition, and WHY setting its background color can resolve this UI-related issue.

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

Comment: Can you post the code to DetailViewController, I suspect something funny is happening in your viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear etc

Comment: I don't touch up those inherited functions yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default background colour for your new viewController is clear, so when you do an animated push you can see through the new viewController temporarily as it pushes itself on top of the navigation stack.

Setting an opaque background colour will mean that your new VC is not transparent, and thus you won't be able to see through it to the VC underneath.

However, I'd recommend you set your `backgroundColor` in `viewDidLoad` of your new viewcontroller, instead of in the one that's doing the presenting (it's not really the responsibility of your presenting viewController to do that).

Answer (score -1):

Try setting a background colour of the detail view in the `init` method ?

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```